# React-Native Avatar. Fix ImageRadius to make all avatars equal

Tags: image, react-native, react-props

Focusing only in renderItem and FlatList.
Avatars are being displayed like this.

Some are circles some with rounded corners and defaultSource avatar are squares.

Can't seem to find a solution..

I've tried using borderRadius as an Image prop instead of using inside of the Image style.

```
renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <ListItem
            bottomDivider={true}
            Component={TouchableScale}
            friction={90}
            tension={100}
            activeScale={0.95}
            title={item.name}
            titleStyle={styles.titleStyle}
            subtitle={item.email}
            subtitleStyle={styles.subStyle}
            leftAvatar={<Image source={{uri: 'my URL'}}
                               defaultSource={require('../resources/defaultAvatar.png')}
                               style={{width: 45, height: 45, borderRadius: 80}}
                               resizeMode={'contain'}/>}
            onPress={() => this.onUserPress(item)}
            chevronColor="white"
            chevron
        />
    )

    render() {
        const {search} = this.state;
        return (
            <View>
                <SearchBar
                    platform={"ios"}
                    ref={search => this.search = search}
                    placeholder={'Escrever aqui...'}
                    color={'#808080'}
                    onChangeText={this.SearchFilterFunction}
                    value={search}
                    round={true}
                    inputStyle={{fontSize: 16}}
                    inputContainerStyle={{height: 35}}
                    containerStyle={{height: 53}}
                    showLoading={true}
                />
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.usersFilter.sort((a, b) => a.name.toString().localeCompare(b.name))}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

I would like to all avatars being formatted properly.

I uploaded app print in comments!

Comment: [APP print](https://imgur.com/vAVMCbs)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

borderRadius: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 60 : 100
```

Try this, it works fine for me.